# firebase get only required data javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using get() to read data into my react native app, using the following..

```
    firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("users")
  .doc("test")
  .get()
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

I only want the test document, but what I'm getting is a 17000 line json doc, it does contain the data I need but the doc I'm after only has one field!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var leadsRef = database.ref('users');
leadsRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
    });
});
```

Now childSnapshot will contain the required data, the same thing can also be accessed using child_added:

```
leadsRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
      //Do something with the data
});
```

Just use the forEach

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to use response.data() rather than just response!